# Repeating function will result in type-error is not a function

Tags: javascript

My program is supposed a quiz that users need to answer questions. After answering, it will show the user a summary. Then prompt the user 0=submit. 1=redo questions.

The error is that. If users chooses to redo the question. After redoing, it will show the summary but will no longer prompt for submitting.

Resulting in submit function = not a function

```
  function showquestion() {

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        console.log("\n" + "Question" + "(" + (i + 1) + ")  " + quiz.mcqSelected[i].getQuestion() + "\n")
        useranswer = parseInt(input.question("Please select your answer ")) + "\n"
        answerstorage.push(useranswer);
        console.log("You have selected answer:" + quiz.questionPool[i].choices[(parseInt(answerstorage[i])) - 1])
        // break
    }
    showsummary();
}

function showsummary() {
    console.log("Here are your answers:\n")
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        console.log("\n" + "Question" + "(" + (i + 1) + ")  " + quiz.mcqSelected[i].getQuestion() + "\n")
        console.log("Answer: " + quiz.questionPool[i].choices[(parseInt(answerstorage[i])) - 1])
    }
    submit();
}

function submit() {
    submit = parseInt(input.question("Enter 0 to submit your quiz, 1 to change your answer or any other keys to reselect category"));
    if (submit == 0) {
        console.log("You have submited your quiz.")
    } else  (submit == 1) {showquestion()}
}
```

Comment: the question function is not specified here.

Comment: Sorry, I'm pretty new to javascript. Just started learning.. what do you mean by the question function is not specific and how can I fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're reassigning the function `submit` inside itself, so if you're planning on calling it again, it won't work. You're basically doing this:

```js
function foo() {
  foo = "I'm a string now";
}

foo();
console.log( typeof foo );
console.log( foo );
foo();
```

Note how the type of `foo` is now a string, after calling the function once, since I reassigned `foo` at `foo = "foo"`.

You could use a different variable for the result of `input.question("Enter 0 to submit your quiz, ...`, e.g:

```
function submit() {
    const answer = parseInt(input.question("Enter 0 to submit your quiz, 1 to change your answer or any other keys to reselect category"));
    if (answer == 0) {
        console.log("You have submited your quiz.")
    } else  (answer == 1) {showquestion()}
}
```

Comment: I don't really understand how it is a string. As it will only run submit if only summary function is called.  Not sure what you mean by it will become a string.

Comment: The function is called `foo`. If you reassign `foo` to something else, such as a _string_ in my case (`foo = "foo"`), it won't be a function anymore, will it? In your case you reassigned your `submit` function to either `0` or `1`, so it won't be a function anymore, but rather a number.

Comment: Basically, since I reassigned my variable submit to 1 or 0. When i call the function to submit again. it will be submit(1)?

Comment: A function can be reassigned just as a simple variable could. If I have a variable `let name = "Bob"` and then below it write `name = 1`, you know that `name` is now a variable containing `1`, correct? Think of your function as this simple variable. It ceases to become a function, it's just `1` now...

Comment: function and variable are together as one i assume? My submit function is being affected by the submit variable?

Comment: It's not _affected_ by the submit variable, you're using the **exact same** variable. You're reassigning `submit`, not defining a new one.

Comment: Oh. i hope i got it. Basically after the first round, submit =whatever user typed 1 or 0. So when it repeats(It will not promt the user for input because submit=1 or 0. And it will not run the if statement anymore, basically its a empty function. thus it is no longer a function?

Comment: It's not an empty function, it's just `1` now. You're clinging really hard to the idea that a function cannot become something other than a function.  You should really read up on variable and function definition. What you're saying before that makes sense though, submit gets reassigned so indeed it is not what it used to be before.

Comment: What i meant is, Function submit () {1}  the input is being replaced by 1. thus the if will not run.

Comment: Read carefully: Step 1: `let foo = function() {}`, step 2: `foo = 1`, question: What is `foo` now after step 2? This is the exact same thing that you're doing in your code.

Comment: Oh, you're not frustrating me dude, it's cool. `foo = 1`, so... well `foo` is `1`. You're just reassigning the variable to something else.

Comment: basically submit function is just 1 now. the input.question was replaced thus the if statement will not work